# npm fund error for Expo installation - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

Why is my npm failing to install Expo for my React Native environment?

I tried installing it using:

```
npm install -global expo-cli
```

It gives errors like:

> npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

Comment: The package is deprecated. Checkout out the author's message on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-cli